# Can someone explain cheby1 and cheb1ord scipy function parameters

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I have a .wav audio file. I generate a sine wave of the given frequency (let's say 2000Hz). Then i add the sine wave to the file, so i get the file with a "squeak".
Then i need to filter this sine wave out using Chebyshev filter. Here's the code:

```
def filt (signal, frequency, sample_rate):
    wp = 1900
    ws = 1950
    gpass = 0.0001
    gstop = 10
    order, wn = sl.cheb1ord (wp, ws, gpass, gstop, fs = sample_rate)
    sos = sl.cheby1 (order, 0.001, wn,
                     btype='lowpass', output =
                         'sos', fs = sample_rate)
    filtered = sl.sosfilt (sos, signal)
    wp = 2050
    ws = 2100
    order, wn = sl.cheb1ord (wp, ws, gpass, gstop, fs = sample_rate)
    sos = sl.cheby1 (order, 0.01, wn,
                     btype='highpass', output =
                         'sos', fs = sample_rate)
    filtered2 = sl.sosfilt (sos, signal)
    return filtered + filtered2
```

But it doesn't filter out the sine wave. It makes the file quieter, but that's all it does.
Where am i wrong? The amplitude's in a file are all less then 2, so gstop seems sufficiently small.
The file's sample rate is 22500 Hz.

Comment: Did you find something confusing or misleading about the documentation?

Comment: No, i understood everything. What i don't understand is why it doesn't work. Here's what i think i'm doing:
1)Filter frequencies higher than 1900. (allowing max 0.0001 ripple and max 10 attenuation
2) Filter frequencies lower than 2050.
3)Add filtered signals, thus getting a signal without a sine wave.

Comment: Where's the code that actually applies the filter to the file? Separately, did you try plotting the transfer function to make sure it looks like the kind of filter you expect?

Comment: The code gets a bit complicated outside of the scope of the filt function. I'm just trying to make sure that i didn't make any mistakes in filtering function.

Comment: I'll plot the transfer function. Once i learn what it is:) Let me get back to ya